# How do I detect if the user has opened my C# forms app with a file

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to find a way to see if my program was opened with a file (e.g dragging a txt over an EXE to open with), how would I see if the user has opened my EXE with a file, and how do I get the filename of said file.

I tried looking through al the C# Form load events but couldn't find anything that matched.

Comment: What do you mean by open exe with a file?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.commandline

Comment: Or you can inspect the `args` parameter in `static void Main(string[] args)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you drag-n-drop a file on an exe, Windows runs the exe with the file's path as a command-line argument. In your `Main` function, you can add a `string[] args` parameter to access the command-line arguments; you can then check if `args.Length > 0`, and use `args[0]` as your file path.

Example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length > 0)
    {
        string path = args[0];
        // use path here
    }
    else
    {
        // exe was run by itself; no path was given
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: That solved it for me, thank you ever so much!

Comment: Good answer. If you are using C# 11+ you can also use a [list pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#list-patterns): `if (args is [string path, ..])`. It does all in one, check the length and declare the `path` variable and assign the first element to it if the length is >= 1. If you drop the `, ..` it checks for Length == 1. You can also just write `var path`, since the type must not be tested.